# File naming of generic and non generic classes with the same name

Tags: c#, generics

Came across this during a code review and had never seen it before, apparently this is fairly standard.

Two classes one generic and one not with the same name.

```
public class Bacon
{
}
```

Filename    **bacon.cs**

```
public class Bacon<T> : Bacon
{
}
```

Filename **bacon`1.cs**

My question is about the file naming.  Is this correct?  And is there any particular reasoning for this?

Comment: Whenever I have a generic class that inherits from a non-generic base class of the same name, I put them in the same file.

Comment: When you decompile code or navigate with visual studio you will see similar names (e.g. List`1)